# Blockly on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, blockly

I would like to run blockly on Node.js and make the code being executed directly on the server (block by block execution included), without needing to save the XML first and then running it in background; I have tried some modules present on npm but none of them does what I want or it just run a pre-generated XML.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps to do on the server:

1) Install `xmldom` module of node.js:

```
$ npm install xmldom
```

2) Clone google's Closure library ([github](https://github.com/google/closure-library)). Be sure the cloned directory is named "closure-library" and is located at the same directory level as your blockly project, like this: ([image link](https://developers.google.com/blockly/images/closure-directory.png))

[image]

3) Add a javascript `generate.js` in your blockly project folder. Note that here I use blockly xml to generate python code. You need to adjust line 7-10 based on the type of generator you use.

```
global.DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

global.Blockly = require('./blockly_uncompressed.js');
require('./blocks/math.js');
require('./blocks/text.js');
require('./blocks/lists.js');
require('./generators/python.js');
require('./generators/python/math.js');
require('./generators/python/text.js');
require('./generators/python/lists.js');
require('./msg/messages.js');

var fs = require('fs');

var xmlText = process.argv[2];
try {
    var xml = Blockly.Xml.textToDom(xmlText);
    // Create a headless workspace.
    var workspace = new Blockly.Workspace();
    Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace(workspace, xml);
    var code = Blockly.Python.workspaceToCode(workspace);
    console.log(code);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

4) Finally, run node.js on `generate.js` with your pre-generated XML string:

```
$ node generate.js '<xml>...</xml>'
```

Reference:

1) [Headless Blockly](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blockly/7NzkGfZ0iso)

2) [Blockly code generation on the server side](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blockly/N70CBxwENDg)

3) [Building Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/modify/web/building)

Comment: If you're going to post code, which is great, please **post it as plain-text**. This image means that code may as well be locked behind glass.

Comment: I get this error
''' Deprecated call to Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace, swap the arguments.
ReferenceError: document is not defined''' ;
swapping the arguments that error occurrs anyway

Comment: by the way, I can't look at the image because imgur is blocked by the proxy

Comment: @skarux I couldn't reproduce your error. I added some reference though, hopefully they'll be helpful for you. As for the image, you can click the image link to see it.

Comment: Currently, doing the same steps on my workstation it will give me this error: global.Blockly = require('./blockly_uncompressed.js');
Error: Cannot find module './../../../../blockly/core/blocks.js'

Answer (score 0):

1. To fix the error

   > Deprecated call to Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace, swap the arguments.

Change the line `Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace(workspace, xml);` to `Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace(xml, workspace);`

2. To fix the error

   > ReferenceError: document is not defined

   Add the line `Blockly.Events.disable();` before calling `Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace`

Refer to the [link](https://github.com/google/blockly/issues/626)